# Split tuple fields into further fields after LOAD

Tags: apache-pig

I have a bunch of syslog data that looks something like this...

Mon Jan 1 00:00:01 UTC 1970 ServerName  debug crond[123456]: System message telling me something

I'm not sure it's visible in the formatting here, but there is a tab character on each side of the ServerName splitting the string. So loading it initially is pretty easy...

```
A = LOAD '/syslogfiles' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (
date:chararray,
host:chararray,
message:chararray);
```

So now I have a tuple with 3 fields. Here's the next part I'm having trouble with. This is pseudo-code since I can't seem to get it right. I feel like EXTRACT may be what I'm looking for, but it doesn't turn out right.

What I want to do is split each of those fields up further, so like

```
B = FOREACH A <split> date USING PigStorage(' ') AS (
day:chararray,
month:chararray,
numday:int,
time:chararray,
timezone:chararray,
year:int);
```

So now I would have a tuple with 8 fields, (day, month, numday, time, timezone, year, host, message)

I assume if I wanted to use the same technique that answers this question, I could continue splitting the time by : if I wanted to, or the message with some value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `STRSPLIT` builtin UDF.  This returns a tuple.  It's basically a wrapper for Java's [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).  If you provide the `limit` parameter, you will have a predictable length for your tuple, and then you can use `FLATTEN` to promote the fields to the top level:

```
B =
    FOREACH A
    GENERATE
        FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(date, ' ', 6)) AS (
            day:chararray,
            month:chararray,
            numday:int,
            time:chararray,
            timezone:chararray,
            year:int),
        host,
        message;

DESCRIBE B;
B: {day: chararray,month: chararray,numday: int,time: chararray,timezone: chararray,year: int,host: chararray,message: chararray}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first method that comes to mind for a task like this is REGEX_EXTRACT() try somethin like this:

> A = LOAD '/syslogfiles' USING PigStorage('\t') AS ( date:chararray,
>   host:chararray, message:chararray);
>
> B = foreach A generate REGEX_EXTRACT(date, '([A-Za-z]*) [A-Za-z]*
>   [1-31] [1-9]*:[1-9*]:[1-9]* [A-Za-z]* [0-9]*',1) as day:chararray,
>   (date, '[A-Za-z]* ([A-Za-z]*) [1-31] [1-9]*:[1-9*]:[1-9]* [A-Za-z]*
>   [0-9]*',1)  as month:chararray ...

something like the above could probly work, although my regex expressions could probably be made simpler if I thought about it for longer.

Comment: Better would be `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL` so you just run the regex once.